# For Loop returning blank values for query values

Tags: python, pymongo

I'm new to Python so please bear with me.

I have an array named `FUNNEL_STEP_ARRAY` returning the values `i` when I try to print them. However, I want to return the query results `for (i)` in each loop.

```
for i in FUNNEL_STEP_ARRAY:
    print (i) #prints the step name
    y = db.external_funnel.find(
    {"step_id":"\i", "client_timestamp": {"$regex": "2013-10-25T"},
    "application_id":"6083502215600857441"
    }).distinct("user_id")
    print(len(y))
```

When I print the name of the last step in the array I get back the appropriate response, however I can't figure out the appropriate way to have i entered into the query for each loop above.

```
y = db.external_funnel.find(
{"step_id":"Tutorial.TAttackScreen.End", "client_timestamp": {"$regex": "2013-10-25T"},
"application_id":"6083502215600857441"
}).distinct("user_id")
```

> > > print(y)
> > >       ['11856662934482915056', '6822304154484365317', '16907601980584545477', '7754468465932591739', '4035769163970893047', '1722852941393395710', '16289507963782337913', '12342123419828328163', '15183373460796791586', '3923264265959269816', '8842662517796204109', '1330883712013359625', '6130265032042700646', '3280282641258166143', '18002035489108466380', '8584675150263264823', '13183853476835939343', '12332104951386419645', '3477173628398869287', '8625222330019018139', '1937123521362305652', '11430291986398375763', '8051074243207166456', '17635653501888308620']
> > >       print(len(y))
> > >       24

Ideally I'm looking for an output for each (i) that looks like:

Tutorial.TAttackScreen.End
24

Comment: does `step_id` need to have a value of `i` from `FUNNEL_STEP_ARRAY` or have the value `"\i"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, inside the for loop, you're doing `"step_id": "\i"`. What this is doing is literally saying that you want the step id to be the characters "backslash i". Instead, you want to use the *contents* of the variable by simply doing:

```
for i in FUNNEL_STEP_ARRAY:
    y = db.external_funnel.find({
        "step_id": i, 
        "client_timestamp": {"$regex": "2013-10-25T"},
        "application_id":"6083502215600857441"
    }).distinct("user_id")
    print(len(y))
```

Note: it might be better style to use a more explicit name for the `i` variable. For example:

```
for step_id in FUNNEL_STEP_ARRAY:
    y = db.external_funnel.find({
        "step_id": step_id, 
        "client_timestamp": {"$regex": "2013-10-25T"},
        "application_id":"6083502215600857441"
    }).distinct("user_id")
    print(len(y))
```